# Why can't I run my code on eclipse, even though i can build it?

Tags: c++, configuration, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse which i will have to use for my c++ assignments. [image]I have downloaded all the necessary softwares. when i build that "testproject"(that prints hello world), it does not give out any errors, yet when i press the run button, the following message pops up. I have tried "clean" and included MinGW/bin in the "includes" under the properties category. I can't seem to find the solution to this error message. I don't understand why there is a "Launching configuration" either where you have to put in "c/c++ application" in order to run it. Could someone help me?

Comment: See https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/Eclipse/launchconfig.html

Comment: yes I have already tried this, but unfortunately it didn't work. Could you think of any other thing that could be causing this issue?